# Minimum between two functions $\min(f(x), g(x))$

Tags: real-analysis

I found the following equation in a Blog (http://www.bitsofpancake.com/math/minimum-and-maximum-of-two-functions/), which could help me a lot solve a certain problem:

$\min(f(x), g(x))=\frac{f(x)+g(x)–|f(x)–g(x)|}{2}$

The problem is I don't know, how the author came up with that and I never saw it in a textbook or someone else using. Does somebody may have an idea where it comes from or how to verify it.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hint : If $f(x)\ge g(x)$ , then we have $|f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x)$ , otherwise $|f(x)-g(x)|=g(x)-f(x)$